# How can you detect the time zone in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, timezone, silverlight-5.0

How can you detect the time zone in Silverlight? 
This is an out of browser application

Would you use p/Invoke? Does Silverlight support this by default in the time class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TimeZoneInfo.Local](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.local%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)